# Connecting to the Internet with a 3G USB Modem

Tags: linux, ppp, pppoe, pppd

I am trying to establish a connection to the Internet with `wvdial`. Everything is alright but the problem is I can't ping for example `google.ca` or its IP address.

Here is the output of the `wvdial` command:

```
WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.com,wapuser1,wap"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.com,wapuser1,wap"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT 21096000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Jan  1 05:11:06 2000
--> Pid of pppd: 3297
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> local  IP address 172.19.154.90
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> remote IP address 10.0.0.1
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> primary   DNS address 64.71.255.198
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
--> secondary DNS address 64.71.255.253
--> pppd: ([07][08]@[07][08][08][07][08]
```

As you can see, I can clearly get an IP, and typing `ifconfig ppp0` displays this:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:172.19.27.135  P-t-P:10.0.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:74 (74.0 B)  TX bytes:107 (107.0 B)
```

But can't ping anything.

So I know it's not a matter of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Here is the contents of my `wvdial.conf`:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.com,wapuser1,wap"
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99#
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
Username = wapuser1
Password = wap
Baud = 460800
Stupid Mode = 1
```

How can I get this setup to work?

`ip addr show`:

```
9: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 3
link/ppp inet 172.16.29.33 peer 10.0.0.1/32 scope global ppp0
```

`ip route show`:

```
default dev ppp0 scope link 10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.61.19
```

Comment: You will probably also need to include the output of `ip addr show` and `ip route show`. If `ping(1)` doesn't work, how about non-ICMP packet types? UDP or TCP?

Comment: `9: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast st                   ate UNKNOWN qlen 3
    link/ppp
    inet 172.16.29.33 peer 10.0.0.1/32 scope global ppp0

and 

ip route show
default dev ppp0  scope link
10.0.0.1 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.61.19`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem yesterday. Got it to work today. Check the answer to this question.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62417/connected-to-internet-on-ppp0-in-raspberry-pi-3-but-commands-like-ping-curl-not

You need to check if you're able to connect to internet through the ppp0 interface. Enter the following command and check the output `ping -I ppp0 google.com`. If you're able to ping, then your device is connected to the internet.

Then, you can run the command `sudo route add default dev ppp0` to gain internet access.